# Unsafe casting with ArrayList entry

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I can store some values in my all `ArrayList` when I choose option 'a'.
But when I go to option 'b' and try to retrieve what I had typed and store in variable `rq` (to check the number of rooms booked) and using it for loop in option 'b' to loop it. But the all array is empty.

I am also having an "error" when I compile.

In option 'b' for loop, I did this

```
for(int i=0;i<all.get(4);i++)
```

but I get an error: `error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'`

So I decided to cast it.

```
for(int i=0;i<(Integer)all.get(4);i++)
```

There is no error now but compilation seems faulty.

> Note: C:\Users\MegaStore\Desktop\java testing\RoomSelection.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

So I'm wondering if those values I typed in are in the heap, or deleted by the garbage collector when I choose option 'b'.

My code is not fully typed out yet but I want to solve the problem at hand.

My program also needs to record how many add-ons (max is 4) that the user wants and store it. So I am not too sure where to add and store it.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class test123{

public test123()throws InputMismatchException {

    String choiceStr;//initialize choiceStr which is use for reading lines from scanner input
    char choiceChar;//initialize choiceStr which is use for reading character from scanner input
    int choice,rt,rq,ao1,night,ao2,quan;//initialize choiceStr which is use for reading integer from scanner input
    String datee;
    String[] roomType = {"Single Room", "Double Room", "Deluxe Room", "Junior Room", "Suite"}; //Initialize a array for room type
    Integer[] priceRoom = {160,200,280,380,500}; //Initialize a array for room prices
    Integer[] priceAdd = {25,60,70,100}; //Initialize a array for add-on prices
    ArrayList<String> roomAndDate = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> all = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in); //Initialize a scanner input

    System.out.println("Room Selection");
    System.out.println("==============\n");
    System.out.println("[a] Room Type");
    System.out.println("[b] Add-Ons");
    System.out.println("[c] Main Menu");
    System.out.println("Type 'a' to select Room Type and state the desire quantity for each type.");
    System.out.println("Type 'b' to select the Add-Ons.");
    System.out.println("Type 'c' to exit from  the Booking Menu.");
    System.out.println("Please enter your option (a, b or c): ");

    ;
    choiceStr = input.nextLine();
    choiceChar = choiceStr.charAt(0); 

    switch(choiceChar){
        case 'a':   System.out.println("Room Type");
                    System.out.println("=====================================================");
                    System.out.println("(1) Single Room (1 person) - Price: S$160");
                    System.out.println("(2) Double Room (2 persons) - Price: S$200");
                    System.out.println("(3) Deluxe Room (2 persons) - Price: S$280");
                    System.out.println("(4) Junior Suite (2 persons) - Price: S$380");
                    System.out.println("(5) Suite (2 persons) - Price: S$500\n");
                    System.out.println("Enter Room types (Enter '1' to '5')");
                    choice=input.nextInt();
                    while(choice>5){
                        if(choice>5){
                        System.out.println("Please enter number between '1' to '5'!");
                        choice=input.nextInt();
                        }                   
                    }

                    String roomTypess= roomType[choice-1];
                    roomAndDate.add(roomTypess);
                    int storePricee = priceRoom[choice-1];
                    all.add(storePricee);

                    System.out.println("Number of rooms required (maximum 10): ");
                    choice=input.nextInt();
                    while(choice>10){       
                        if(choice>10){
                        System.out.println("Please enter again!");
                        choice=input.nextInt();
                        }
                    }
                    all.add(choice);

                    for(int i=0;i<choice;i++){
                        System.out.println("Enter the date of checked-in (dd/mm/yy) for "+roomAndDate.get(0) +" " + (i+1));
                        choiceStr = input.nextLine();
                        choiceStr = input.nextLine();
                        roomAndDate.add(choiceStr);
                        System.out.println(roomAndDate);
                        System.out.println("Enter number of Add-on for "+roomAndDate.get(0) + " " +(i+1)+": ");
                        choice=input.nextInt();
                        while(choice>4){
                        if(choice>4){   
                            System.out.println("Please enter again! Choose only option 1 to 4");
                            choice=input.nextInt();
                            }                           
                        }
                        all.add(choice);            
                        System.out.println("Number of night(s) required (maximum 30) for "+roomAndDate.get(0) + " " +(i+1)+ ": ");
                        choice=input.nextInt();
                        while(choice>30){   
                            if(choice>30){
                            System.out.println("Please enter again! Maximum is 30 days!");
                            choice=input.nextInt();
                            }
                        }           
                        all.add(choice);


                    }
                    new RoomSelection();

                    break;          
        case 'b':       System.out.println("Room req is empty? : "+all.isEmpty());
                        System.out.println("Add-Ons");
                        System.out.println("=====================================================");
                        System.out.println("(1) Breakfast voucher (1 person) per day - Price: S$25");
                        System.out.println("(2) Spa voucher (1 person) - Price: S$60");
                        System.out.println("(3) Half Day Tour voucher (1 person) - Price: S$70");
                        System.out.println("(4) Full Day Tour voucher (1 person) - Price: $100\n");



                        for(int i=0;i<(Integer)all.get(3);i++){

                        System.out.println("Enter Add-On option");
                        choice=input.nextInt();
                        while(choice>4){
                            if(choice>4){   
                                System.out.println("Please enter again! Choose only option 1 to 4");
                                choice=input.nextInt();
                            }                           
                        }
                        all.add(choice);
                        System.out.println("Enter quantity required for Add-On option " + (i+1)+": ");
                        choice=input.nextInt();
                        all.add(choice);
                        }

                    break;
        case 'c':   new MainPage1();break;
        default:continue;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You're putting multiple types into your array list; unless you keep track of what and where they are, comparing a list entry against an integer won't always work. And keeping track of what and where they are is buggy and error-prone. Consider a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

This is why you should use generics. Currently, looking at the declaration of `all`, neither the compiler nor the reader can see what's meant to be in there. Looking at the code, it seems it's a mixture of strings and integers. That's a recipe for disaster. What is it really meant to represent in the first place? *Why* does it contain a mixture of strings and integers?

It sounds like quite probably you want a `Room` type with all this information in, and `all` should be declared like this:

```
List<Room> allRooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
```

Additionally, this method is *way* too long at the moment. I get nervous when a line goes above about 20 lines... but 130+? Eek! Work out which bits can be extracted - ones which don't affect the rest of the code.

Oh, and learn about array initializers, to turn this:

```
Integer[] priceAdd = new Integer[4]; //Initialize a array for add-on prices
priceAdd[0]=25; //To be added to array add-on price
priceAdd[1]=60; //To be added to array add-on price
priceAdd[2]=70; //To be added to array add-on price
priceAdd[3]=100; //To be added to array add-on price
```

into this:

```
int[] addOnPrices = { 25, 60, 70, 100 };
```

(I can't see any reason why they'd need to be `Integer` rather than `int`, although you're currently assuming you'll never need fractional values...)

Comment: Also, his `switch` statement doesn't loop, so the `ArrayList` he declares is in a local scope and will be empty every time he chooses 'b'.

Comment: @DavidB: I haven't really looked at the details of the code - there's way too much to take in :)

Comment: Your answers are usually very comprehensive, so I thought I'd save you the time. This method is quite ugly and has quite a few problems.

Comment: @DavidB: Just glancing down it, I'm intrigued by `while(ao2>4){ if(ao2>4){ ... } }` too...

Comment: so for int input i juz use one varible like choice to collect all inputs, that would suffice?

Comment: and i also added a while(true) loops , but it still doesnt work. Is there any other way or my while loop is doing wrongly?

Comment: @HengAikHwee: Given that you've got *several* `while` loops, it's hard to say what you're talking about, exactly. I can't understand your previous comment either. But encapsulating information into an appropriate type is likely to *radically* simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the type of the ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<String> all = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or with whatever non-primitive datatype you are using.

Answer (score 1):

`List<Integer> all = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

The above will always accepts and returns Integer values.